# Restart the Datagridview when clicking a button

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to restart the datagridview or more say like to have a new transaction when pressing a button PROCESS ?

[image]

Comment: New transaction as in 'anything that follows a Commit'? Commit!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply,

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourreloadMethod();
    datagridview1.Update();
    datagridview1.Refresh();
}
```

Comment: [`Refresh`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,c0fcbb8eadd8988e) method calls `Update` itself. Also calling refresh or update doesn't have anything to reload data.